# Rails 3 model subclasses driving me CRAZY! Please help with correcting urls/params hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, model, subclass

I have a problem with subclassing Rail's models. Suppose you have a `User` model and several subclasses of it (user types) that store specific methods and associations, for example: `Director`, `Admin`, `Trainee`, `Instructor`, etc. This is just simple "single-table inheritance". The problem is 2-fold.

1. paths/urls often crash or do weird things when you pass a subclass rather than the base class. Here's an example:

   ```
   <% if user.enabled? %>
     <%= link_to 'Disable', disable_user_path(user) %>
   <% else %>
     <%= link_to 'Enable', enable_user_path(user) %>
   <% end %>
   ```

   If you pass in a `User` model, it works just fine. But if you pass a subclass, like `Admin`, it throws this exception:

   ```
   No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"disable", :id=>#<Admin id: 1, first_name: "Ken", ..., created_at: "2011-05-23 21:01:35", updated_at: "2011-05-23 21:04:28">}
   ```

   Clearly, this is not behaving correctly. How can we get rails to use the base class all the time?
2. Even more disturbing is forms (I am using `simple_form`). Let's say you have a `/profile` form. You want all `User` subclasses to access it equally, and you don't want to deal with their subclasses on a special-case basis; it should be 100% generic.

   For some reason, if the user is an `Admin`, it will post the params hash as

   ```
   params[:admin]
   ```

   Even worse, if you view the source of the form, it actually says `user[first_name]` instead of `admin[first_name]`, so something is definitely screwy! The instance variable is `@user` too, so I don't see why it should be posting to `params[:admin]`.

Here is the form view code for (2):

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user, :url => profiles_path, :method => :put, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Personal Information</legend>
      <%= f.input :first_name %>
      <%= f.input :last_name %>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Credentials</legend>
      <%= f.input :email %>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Preferences</legend>
      <%= f.input :receive_email_notifications %>
      <%= f.input :receive_newsletters %>
      <%= f.input :allow_private_messages %>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Avatar</legend>
      <p>
          Select an image from your computer to use as your avatar. You will be given the oppurtunity
          to crop this image further after your image has been uploaded.
      </p>
      <%= f.input :avatar, :as => :file, :label => "Select File" %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :avatar_cache %>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.button :submit, :value => "Update Profile" %>
      <%= link_to 'Cancel', profiles_path %>
    </div>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Here are the controller actions to first render the view and when I submit the form:

```
  def edit
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)

    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user]) # <-- this bombs for Admin subclass
      if params[:user][:avatar] # <-- this would bomb also.
        redirect_to(crop_avatar_profiles_path)
      else
        redirect_to(profiles_path, :notice => 'Your profile was successfully updated.')
      end
    else
      render :action => "edit"
    end
  end

  def crop_avatar
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  end

  def update_avatar
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @user.crop(params[:x].to_i, params[:y].to_i, params[:h].to_i, params[:w].to_i)

    redirect_to(profiles_path, :notice => 'Your profile and avatar was successfully updated.')
  end
```

Besides thinking up some pretty inelegant solutions (especially to the forms problem), I am at a loss as to how I can fix them. There has to be a better way to deal with these situations.

Comment: what kind of subclasses are you talking about? Your question is vague

Comment: It sounds like you are doing things in an non-standard way if you are creating an Admin subclass of User.

Comment: As for your 2nd point, could you post the form view code as well as the controller actions which render it and receive the post?

Comment: @Ben Moss: I could be. I don't see what's wrong with having subclasses for User though. Every type of user in my application has totally different associations. It does not make sense to put them all in the base User model.

Comment: @mosch: Added the code so you can see what I mean.

Comment: You suggest that your edit action would render the form with a Admin Instance in some cases, which I don't believe to be possible with `@user = User.find(current_user.id)`. Could you clarify this? Rails infers param names from model names. So subclassing the user roles in the way you are doing it leads to a params[:admin] hash.

Comment: @mosch: How can I fix it? Even if I have to re-design it... I'd be happy to if it meant I could get rid of these problems. I just want it to be known that each User is not made equal in this application. For example, a Trainee can take Courses, but a CourseProvider cannot. It does not make sense for the CourseProvider to "have many courses" if you know what I mean. I have tons and tons of cases like this for users. In Java, I can do this sort of domain-driven design no problem. Please say I can do it in Rails

Comment: @mosch: I also want to add that not being able to design a User with subclasses in Rails kind of defeats the whole purpose for a language to offer Polymorphism. Not only do I need to separate out associations, but I will definitely have polymorphic methods that need to respond differently depending on their user subclass. Inheritance/Polymorphism is truly the natural way to design my application - it's not just "the java way" - it's the OO way. Ruby is OO - we should be able to do this :/

Comment: I would personally approach the problem with a role attribute on the User model which then would contain "trainee", "course_provider", etc. But about single table inheritance: Did you have a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html and do you have the type column?

Comment: I see your point. In the view, did you try adding :as => :user to the form_for method?

Comment: Actually, Carlos @ simple_form just told me about :as => :user and it works for the forms :) Yay. It doesn't pass in some of the tests though, but I'll deal with that later.

Comment: Yay, I fixed it. I just needed :url => edit_user_path(@user), :as => :user and that works and makes the tests pass when they render the views! YAY!!!!! If you answer the question Mosch, I can give you the checkmark

Comment: Yeah, my instinct would be to use [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki) for handling the different User roles rather than subclasses. Anyway sounds like you have it solved for the time being.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem with STI due to the dynamic casting rails did for me. I solved it using the **becomes** method.

In your User model:

```
    #return an array [User, User, ...], instead of [Admin, Director, Director, Instructor, ...]
    def self.all_without_typecast
      self.all.collect! do |u|
          u.becomes(User)
      end
    end

    #makes subclasses of User (Admin, Director, ...) into User class
    def userize #cast_into_user could be a better name
      self.becomes(User)
    end
```

Now whenever you don't want a user instance to be of an specific type (Admin, Director..) but just User, you can do:

```
    @user = @user.userize
```

And your @user object will now be treated as a User, not Admin or Director or whatever, same goes for all_without_typecast, like this:

```
    @users = User.all_without_typecast # if you're having problems with User.all
```

Maybe this methods could be run before each scope so you don't have to rewrite every one of them.
Hope it helps!

Comment: That's certainly a fancy work-around. Now that I've discovered :as => :user, I hope that'll be enough. If not, your solution seems like the answer. It's a shame Rails isn't OO-aware. You got a language that is even more OO than Java is... but Rails is so opinionated that it actually makes it a little hard to do OO in your models.

Answer (score 7):

```
= simple_form_for @fruit, :as => :fruit do |form|
```

`@fruit` can be any class (Orange, Apple, Pear) and it will still prefix the inputs with 'fruit' thus giving a `params[:fruit]` everytime.

Comment: I revisited this question myself...I think this solution is way better than mine :)

Comment: This is better for sure, but what do you do when you have a nested resource like: simple_form_for [@fruit, @core] ? Is there a way to specify the 'as' for @fruit?

Comment: @NimaIzadi You can call it whatever you like, e.g. `:as => 'fruit_core'` will become `params[:fruit_core]`. It's no differrent.

Comment: I know, but I want to change the name for the url not for the params name.
If you do `simple_form_for [@fruit, @core]` and fruit is an apple you will have your url like `apple/:fruite_apple_id/core/:id` when I'd like to have `fruit/:fruit_id/core/:id`